# How to implement progress bar in javafx with time elapsed and estimated time remaining values?

Tags: java, javafx

How to implement a progress bar in javafx with time elapsed and time remaining values in the bar? Kindly provide any sample programs if possible.

Comment: Do you want to show the values over the bar or just next to it?

Comment: I need to display estimated time remaining below the progress bar and the elapsed time above the progress bar. This progress bar is for background queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on how to use it in the oracle docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/progress.htm